# Two ajax call using in one Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have nested Ajax calls, which I wrote the second in the middle of first one Success part as of the following, but I cant access the result of the second call outside:

```
success: function (result) {
 //I need to pass the "result" to a function outside of this bracket 
}
```

Comment: Just place the function call in the `success` handler, passing the variable you need. What's the issue?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  how?i just need the "result" outside this scope

Comment: You cannot get the `result` outside of this scope. That's not how asynchronous code works. However your original issue was calling another function and passing that as a parameter, which you can do in the standard way, eg. `myOtherFunction(result);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you mean if I want to get the "result" out of this scope I should create a function like myOtherFunction(result) ?but then I need to change the success:function(result) to success:myOtherFunction(result)?

Comment: No, just call that function within the handler: `success: function(result) { myOtherFunction(result); },` or pass it as the reference: `success: myOtherFunction,`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  success: function (data) {myfunction(data); } you mean this ,right?im really sorry for to much asking,confused somehow,but still not able to call this and get the data,how would you write the function outside of the scope?